# Some externally-linked CSS working, some not

Tags: html, css

I am working on a photo portfolio website using Django framework. On the current page, I have one photo element and one box element with text inside. My CSS is linked externally in the html script tag. The CSS for the photo is being applied, but the CSS for the box is not. When I move the box CSS into a style tag on my html document, it is applied.

I've searched and found some information on CSS priority but I don't think that's what's happening here as some of the CSS works externally. I've also taken a look via Inspect in Chrome to see if something was being applied that I didn't know about, but didn't see anything.

Has anyone experienced this before? Even stranger, in the full code below, the CSS is applied to the box element!

```css
#box {
    background-color: lightgray;
    width: 300px;
    border: 15px solid green;
    padding: 50px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load static %}
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'entrance/entrance.css' %}">
        <script src="{% static 'entrance/entrance.js' %}"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <img src="{% static 'entrance/Waterfall.jpg' %}" alt="issue here" id="waterfall" />
        <div id="box">This is just some random text I'm using to test the box design.</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "My CSS is linked externally in the html script tag"?

Comment: My mistake. I meant linked in the html link tag. Fixed now.

Comment: Please do not edit solution announcements into the question. Accept (i.e. click the "tick" next to it) one of the existing answer, if there are any. You can also create your own answer, and even accept it, if your solution is not yet covered by an existing answer. Compare https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: @Yunnosch Got it. Thanks for explaining.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try refreshing by pressing Ctrl+Shift+R. This refreshes the cache and the previously saved css could be the only thing running.